# How to get form data from Postman To WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, postman, form-data

I want to receive form data from Postman:

[image]

`Content-Type: application/json`

Here is WebApi method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/test")]
public async Task TestMethod(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var test = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

What I'm getting is:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarypqDvmeG89cBR9mK9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"

esad
------WebKitFormBoundarypqDvmeG89cBR9mK9--
```

But I don't want data with `WebKitFormBoundary` and I've restriction to use formdata only. Is there any other way?

HTTP call information:

```
POST /api/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:16854
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 1a3d6427-4956-707d-da0c-3a29a63c7563

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"

esad
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Curl call information:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:16854/api/test \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'postman-token: 02055873-e9a8-e9a6-019c-b407992b0e2f' \
  -F test=esad
```

Comment: Where was this WebApi method placed in your code? I'm having issues getting it started with my MvcApplication...

Answer (score 18):

**1) If you have to send `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` OR simply `form-data`**

*This is the first `tab` of Postman*

[image]

If you have to collect only one key/value pair of your posted `form-data`

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/test")]
public HttpResponseMessage TestMethod(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var testValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["test"];

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, testValue);
}
```

If you have to collect more than one key/value pair of your posted `form-data`

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/test")]
public HttpResponseMessage TestMethod(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    NameValueCollection collection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;

    var items = collection.AllKeys.SelectMany(collection.GetValues, (k, v) => new { key = k, value = v });

    //We just collect your multiple form data key/value pair in this dictinary
    //The following code will be replaced by yours
    Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        keyValuePairs.Add(item.key, item.value);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, keyValuePairs);
}
```

---

**2) If you have to send `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**

*This is the second `tab` of Postman*

[image]

Then your API will be

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/test")]
public async Task TestMethod(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var test = await request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();
}
```

Then you will get following output when you debug your code with breakpoint

[image]

---

**3) If you have to send `Content-Type: application/json`**

*This is the third `tab` of Postman*

See below screenshot for such option

[image]

And your api is

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/test")]
public async Task TestMethod(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
     var jObject = await request.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>();

     Item item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(jObject.ToString());
}
```

And your model to collect this posted data

```
public class Item
{
    public string test { get; set; }
}
```

And your output will be

[image]

The advantage of this option you can send `complex type` as posted data and like

[image]

And your api is

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public async Task TestMethod(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var jObject = await request.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>();

    Sample sample = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sample>(jObject.ToString());
}
```

And you model to collect this data are

```
public class Item
{
    public string test { get; set; }
}

public class Sample
{
    public Item item { get; set; }
}
```

And you will see the output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that is what I already stated `I've restriction to use formdata only`

Comment: Is you have requirement to use async/await?

Comment: Nope, anyhow I want to get `form-data`

Comment: Thanks! but what you have added is row json data, not form data :)

Comment: How can we get the `headers` data ?

Comment: @Faisal, try this => `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers` and use linq to get your key value pair

Comment: @er-sho thank you but can you please also add the method to get data from associated arrays `[{"msn":"002994000002","global_device_id":"a002"},
{"msn":"002994000001","global_device_id":"a001"}]`

Comment: @Faisal, Until I'll add new code for you, you can try this => `var jArray = await request.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>();  
List<Sample> lstSamples = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sample>>(jArray.ToString())  `  where `Sample` is your class that contains your properties of msn and global_device_id

Answer (score 1):

The following code will read key/value correctly when sent from Postman with `form-data` option selected

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/test")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> TestMethod(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    var testValue = provider.FormData.GetValues("test")[0];

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

A more thorough example can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2#reading-form-control-data) (Section: *Reading Form Control Data*).

Edit: The HTTP call that is sent to the above API handler is the one below:

```
POST /api/stats/testmethod HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4100
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 999fd13d-f804-4a63-b4df-989b660bcbc5
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"

esad
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but getting error on awaiting: `"ExceptionMessage": "Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a content type header starting with 'multipart/'.\r\nParameter name: content",`
}`

Comment: @HinaKhuman Can you share the curl command from the API call you try from Postman?

Comment: Not sure about curl command, I'm using `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: @HinaKhuman I have tried the above code with `Content-Type: application/json` and it works fine. Postman has a [Code option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF11j.png) where you can export in cURL, C#, etc. Can you post the code from there so to see how exactly the API call is made?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, added to the question

Comment: @HinaKhuman The snippet you posted is the HTTP call, not the cURL command. Yet, I was able to setup an identical HTTP call in Postman, but still get no error. I tried also in a new and empty project, no error there as well. The error message you posted states that there is no header starting with `multipart/`but as you can see there is a such header in the HTTP call. I cannot think of anything else to check at the moment, so would you mind the actual cURL snippet? When you click *Code* in Postman there is a dropdown with available languages to choose, and one of them is cURL.

Comment: I saw the cURL and its the same with my example. Not sure what else we could check.

Comment: Alright, no issues, I will check it tomorrow morning, i think what I need is some fresh air :) Thanks for your effort Tasos, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Below statement can do this:

```
NameValueCollection form = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
```