# How to receive `multipart/mixed` in an ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: http, asp.net-core, multipart

Legacy systems will send me this:

```
POST /xml HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 321
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=------------------------a9dd0ab37a224967

--------------------------a9dd0ab37a224967
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="part1"
Content-Type: text/xml

<foo>bar</foo>
--------------------------a9dd0ab37a224967
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="part2"
Content-Type: application/json

{'foo': 'bar'}
--------------------------a9dd0ab37a224967--
```

The first part I need to interpret as raw `XElement`; for the second part I would like the usual model binding.

I try this:

```cs
class Part2 { 
    public string foo { get; set; }
}
    

[HttpPost]
[Route("/xml")]
public string Post1([FromBody] XElement part1, [FromBody] Part2 part2 )
{
    return part1.ToString() + ", " + part2.foo;
}
```

But ASP.NET does not allow more than one parameter decorated with `[FromBody]`.

How do I make my ASP.NET Core service receive http requests with content-type `multipart/mixed`?

Comment: This is a follow-up to my previous question on interpreting raw xml [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383967/how-to-read-raw-xml-from-request-body-in-aspnet).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism to handle this type of post data (`multipart/mixed` has virtually unlimited possibilities, and it would be hard to bind to it in a generic sense), but, you can easily parse the data yourself using the [`MultipartReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.multipartreader) object.

I am going to assume that all the data that is coming in has a disposition of `attachment` and that only JSON and XML content-types are valid. But this should be open-ended enough for you to modify as you see fit.

Take a look at this static helper:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Text;

namespace YourNamespace.Utilities
{
    public static class MutipartMixedHelper
    {
        public static async IAsyncEnumerable<ParsedSection> ParseMultipartMixedRequestAsync(HttpRequest request)
        {
            // Extract, sanitize and validate boundry
            var boundary = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(
                MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(request.ContentType).Boundary).Value;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(boundary) ||
                (boundary.Length > new FormOptions().MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit))
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException("boundry is shot");
            }

            // Create a new reader based on that boundry
            var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, request.Body);

            // Start reading sections from the MultipartReader until there are no more
            MultipartSection section;
            while ((section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync()) != null)
            {
                // parse the content type
                var contentType = new ContentType(section.ContentType);

                // create a new ParsedSecion and start filling in the details
                var parsedSection = new ParsedSection
                {
                    IsJson = contentType.MediaType.Equals("application/json",
                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
                    IsXml = contentType.MediaType.Equals("text/xml",
                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
                    Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(contentType.CharSet)
                };

                // Must be XML or JSON
                if (!parsedSection.IsXml && !parsedSection.IsJson)
                {
                    throw new InvalidDataException("only handling json/xml");
                }

                // Parse the content disosition
                if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(
                        section.ContentDisposition, out var contentDisposition) &&
                        contentDisposition.DispositionType.Equals("attachment"))
                {
                    // save the name
                    parsedSection.Name = contentDisposition.Name.Value;

                    // Create a new StreamReader using the proper encoding and
                    // leave the underlying stream open
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(
                        section.Body, parsedSection.Encoding, leaveOpen: true))
                    {
                        parsedSection.Data = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        yield return parsedSection;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class ParsedSection
    {
        public bool IsJson { get; set; }
        public bool IsXml { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public Encoding Encoding { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can call this method from your endpoint, like so:

```cs
[HttpPost, Route("TestMultipartMixedPost")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestMe()
{
    await foreach (var parsedSection in MutipartMixedHelper
        .ParseMultipartMixedRequestAsync(Request))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Name: {parsedSection.Name}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Encoding: {parsedSection.Encoding.EncodingName}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"IsJson: {parsedSection.IsJson}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"IsXml: {parsedSection.IsXml}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Data: {parsedSection.Data}");
        Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------");
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Your endpoint would output:

```
Name: part1
Encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)
IsJson: False
IsXml: True
Data: <foo>bar</foo>
-----------------------
Name: part2
Encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)
IsJson: True
IsXml: False
Data: {"foo": "bar"}
-----------------------
```

At this point, you'd have to deserialize based on the properties of the returned objects.

Comment: @SørenDebois -- absolutely! If you get stuck or can't figure something out, just let me know an I will be more than happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** that `[FromBody]` **doesn't work here** as it specifically designed to accept simple form data (e.g `"multipart/form-data"` type) suitable for processing via the `POST` request method.

You may look for something like [Batch Processing in OData](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/). Considering that, Sending data through RFC 2045/2046 is not a typical way for web application communications. Actually, This is designed for Email communications. This is why you see poor information for Asp.net implementation.

Following [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383967/how-to-read-raw-xml-from-request-body-in-aspnet), Another answer could be sending a raw text (xml formatted) to the controller and then trying to parse and do another operations. Try to keep the client-server communication simple. Here, there's no reason to make it complex using *MultipartMixed* method while modern and large scale projects use typical ways.